# Reading a secret from Azure Key Vault takes a long time

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

As the title says I'm currently having an issue where the following piece of code take 20+ seconds to execute.

```
var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
             new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
var secret = await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync(vaultBaseUrl, secretName).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

[image]

The Secret is read eventually but I feel this is an excessive amount of time to wait. I have yet to find anyone with a similar issue.

First time using Key Vault, am I possibly not accessing it correctly?

Comment: I have a possibly related issue posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53487888/apparent-delay-in-azure-keyvault-access

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (on my development machine) and the reason was, that AzureServiceTokenProvider seems first to try a local url's that time out which is probably the better setting when running on Azure but not for local development.

The solution for me was to set the environment variable `AzureServicesAuthConnectionString` to the value `RunAs=Developer; DeveloperTool=VisualStudio` on my dev machine.

See also this github issue https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/4645

Comment: I had to use `DeveloperTool=AzureCli` instead of `DeveloperTool=VisualStudio`, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61166447/543814).

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! Huge. Saves me 55s.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the stopwatch *after* you retrieve your access token from AAD and ending it once you retrieve the secret. I suspect the delay is during the retrieval of the token.

Personally I found it was quicker to just get the token yourself when I created an app that used Azure APIs.

Comment: Yeah same thing, it's the GetSecretAsync that seems to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

1. The SLA for Azure Key Vault Service is supposed to be much better
   than what you're observing here. I mention it here because if all
   else fails, you could take this up with Microsoft Support and they
   should be able to help.
        [SLA for Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/key-vault/v1_0/)

   > We guarantee that we will process Key Vault transactions within 5
   >   seconds at least 99.9% of the time.
2. Check **which region did you create your Key Vault in**? Is your application (where you're accessing it from) in a completely different region by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for the SLA info. Yes both Key Vault and App are in the same location.

Comment: Are you running this from inside an Azure Function or App Service?

Comment: I have an Azure Function that references a .NET Framework Class library which gets the secret.