# Apparent delay in Azure KeyVault access

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-keyvault

We have an Azure-based ASP.NET Web Service that accesses an Azure KeyVault.  We are seeing two instances in which a method "hangs" on a first try, and then works a minute or so later.

In both instances, a KeyVault access occurs.  In both instances the problem started when we started using the KeyVault in these methods.

We have done very careful logging in the first instance, and cannot see anything else in our code that could cause the hang.  The KeyVault access is the primary suspect.

In addition, if we run the app from our local servers (from Visual Studio), the KeyVault access works fine on the "first try".  It only produces the "hang" error when it runs in production on Azure, and only on that "first try".

By "hang" I mean that in one instance, which is triggered by an external API,  it takes at least 60 seconds (we can tell that because the external API times out.)  In the other instance, which is triggered by a page request, several minutes can pass and the page just spins, at which point we assume the DB request or something else has timed out.

When I say "a minute or so later", that's as fast as we have timed the retry.

Is there some kind of issue or function where the KeyVault needs to be "warmed up" before it works on the first try?

Update:  I'm looking at the code more carefully, and I see at least a couple of places where we can insert still more logging to get a more exact picture of where the failure occurs.  I'm going to do that, and then I'll report back here.

Update:  See answer below - major newbie error, has been corrected.

Comment: could you share the code that causes the problem ? also are you using managed identity to connect to key vault ?

Comment: Prompted by your comment, I was prepping to share snippets,  and saw ways to do more logging.  I'm going to try that first.  Interaction => smarter action.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem, and the solution.

Key Vault access needs to be called from an async task, because there is a multi-second delay.

```
private async Task<string> GetKeyVaultSecretValue(varSecretParms) {
```

I don't understand the underlying technology, however, apparently, if the call is from within a standard code sequence, the server doesn't like to wait, and so the thread is abandoned/halts.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems that it dues to WebApp that **does not enable Always on** .

> By default, web apps are **unloaded** if they are idle for some period of time. This lets the system conserve resources. In Basic or Standard mode, you can enable Always On to keep the app loaded all the time

If possible, please have a try to enable [Always on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-configure#application-settings) and try it again.

Comment: Thanks, "always on" is already set.  We have now found the Key Vault delay problem in two other places.  We're trying to set up KeyVault logging and found a snag, so that first.

Comment: "Always on" is a stupid solution. The reason that web apps are unloaded is to conserve memory on the server. Sure "always on" is faster because the apps don't need to access the key vault (all the secrets are in memory!). In that case why even have a key vault? I can just store the secrets in memory, and set them with a POST api.